# Pattern and Matcher java problem

Tags: java, regex

> "SOMETHING, SOMETHING1,
>   SOMETHING2,..."

How can I split that string to

> SOMETHING SOMETHING1 SOMETHING2

This is what I have at the moment:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\,+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(nVI);
while(m.find()){
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

However, it is not producing the desired result.

Comment: Why cant you use string.split() option and split on `,` character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What exactly separates the parts? Just a comma and a single space?

Try this:

```
String[] parts = nVI.split(", ");
```

There is no need to escape the comma by writing `\\,` in your regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "SOMETHING, SOMETHING1, SOMETHING2";
String[] stringList = s.split(", ");

for(String str : stringList){
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more generic solution (splitting by non-word characters):

```
String[] stringList = s.split("\\W+");
```

From the [Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) javadocs:

```
\w  A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]
\W  A non-word character: [^\w]
```

---

Or if you use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), you can do the equivalent (actually not quite equivalent, as it also matches non-ascii letters):

```
for(String word:
Splitter.on(CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER_OR_DIGIT.negate()).split(str)){
    // do something
}
```